# how to disable a button if dialog box is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

how can i make a button with the id `#createEditListCloseBtn` get disabled if a dialog box with the id `#acronyms` is empty? 
I've tried the following:

```
 if($("#acronyms").children("option:selected").length < 1)
 {
    $("#createEditListSaveBtn").addClass("state-btn-disabled")
                               .attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean a text box when you say dialog box?

Comment: i mean a box with a list, like a list of acronyms  for example

Comment: Can you provide an example of the html that you are using to create this box with a list? What html tag are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#username").val().length >= 1 && $("#password").val().length >= 1) {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}, 100);
```

It checks the values of two fields if they are equal or more than "1" and if so, it enables the submit button.

FIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/nn8s2e8h/

Comment: Forgot about prop! Nice job.

Comment: Or you could replace the contents of the function with `$("#submit").prop("disabled", !($("#username").val().length >= 1 && $("#password").val().length >= 1));`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I feel like that takes the readability down. Is there a  reason to use that instead of what is already in the answer, other than you can?

Comment: Just personal preference. Writing `if(myBool) { f(true); } else { f(false); }` is a little long-winded when you can just write. `f(myBool);`. Some people may not realise you can do this. My version does make the line rather long though. You can split it into two lines: `var wantEnabled = $("#username").val().length >= 1 && $("#password").val().length >= 1; $("#submit").prop("disabled", ! wantEnabled);`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your function only runs once when the page loads, then what you need is an event handler:

```
function updateDisabledStatus() {
    if($("#acronyms").children("option:selected").length < 1)
    {
       $("#createEditListSaveBtn").addClass("state-btn-disabled")
                                  .attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
       $("#createEditListSaveBtn").removeClass("state-btn-disabled")
                                  .removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
updateDisabledStatus();
$("#acronyms").on('change', updateDisabledStatus);
```

Unlike captain theo's answer, this doesn't waste the user's processing power checking the status 10 times a second.

Incidentally, do you really need to have a CSS class *and* a disabled attribute?